# When using ansible conditionals can you tell ansible to perform an alternative action when encountering an error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

So I have this code

```
- name: exectuing aws cli engine
  become: yes
  command: sh /tmp/aws/install
  register: aws_cli
- debug: msg={{ aws_cli.stdout }}
```

and when executed produces this error as a result of aws cli already being installed

```
fatal: [Jenkins_server]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "sh",
        "/tmp/aws/install"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:00.808705",
    "end": "2020-11-19 19:50:31.133925",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "sh /tmp/aws/install",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2020-11-19 19:50:30.325220",
    "stderr": "Found preexisting AWS CLI installation: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current. Please rerun install script with --update flag.",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Found preexisting AWS CLI installation: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current. Please rerun install script with --update flag."
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

this fine but my question is
when aws_cli.rc == 1

is it possible to tel ansible to skip running
this code

```
command: sh /tmp/aws/install
```

and run the update aws cli command instead? so something like

```
command: sh /tmp/aws/install --update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, two ways: [`ignore_errors: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-118) or use a [`block:` with `rescue:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks)

Option 1:

```yaml
- name: exectuing aws cli engine
  become: yes
  command: sh /tmp/aws/install
  register: aws_cli
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: exectuing aws cli engine, 2nd try
  when: aws_cli is failed
  become: yes
  command: sh /tmp/aws/install --update
  register: aws_cli
```

Option 2:

```yaml
- block:
  - name: exectuing aws cli engine
    become: yes
    command: sh /tmp/aws/install
    register: aws_cli
  rescue:
  - name: exectuing aws cli engine, 2nd attempt
    become: yes
    command: sh /tmp/aws/install --upgrade
    register: aws_cli
```